# Is minimizer in reproducing kernel hilbert space the same as in L2 space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

In detail, $\mathcal{H}$ is a reproducing kernel hilbert space (RKHS), and $f^*$ is fixed.

Problem 1 is 
$$f(x) \in \underset{g\in \mathcal{H}}{arg min} \Vert f^*(x) -g(x)\Vert_{\mathcal{H}}$$

Problem 2 is

$$f'(x) \in \underset{g\in \mathcal{H}}{arg min} \Vert f^*(x) -g(x)\Vert_{\mathcal{L}_2}$$

Are $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ the same?

In my understanding, it should be the same but I only have a vague feeling. Since 
$$\Vert f^*(x) -g(x)\Vert_{\mathcal{L}_2}\leq\Vert f^*(x) -g(x)\Vert_{\mathcal{H}}K(x,x)$$
and 
$$\Vert f^*(x) -g(x)\Vert_{\mathcal{H}}\leq\Vert f^*(x) -g(x)\Vert_{\mathcal{L}_2}\Vert P_{K,X}\Vert_{\mathcal{L}_2}$$
where $P_{K,X}$ is the power function from the book $\textit{Scattered Data Approximation}$.